# Rails 3 - How to Link to a User given a user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm outputting comments on a /books/1

I have the following:

```
<%= comment.user.id%>  ---- This gives the correct user_id
```

What I want to do is create:

```
<%= link_to comment.user.fname, XXXXXXXXXXXXXX %>
```

What I don't know what to put for XXXXXXXXXXXXXX that links to /users/1
1 being the id from the comment.user.id

Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= link_to comment.user.fname, comment.user %>
```

Should do exactly what you want.

Comment: God I love Rails.. I had figured out "User.find(comment.user.id)" but your solution is way better!